# Extract substring from string using key pattern and delimiter using Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I extract substring from a string using key pattern and delimiter. e.g.

```
mystring = 'toto=1,2,3 mynames=ralf,john,franky myhobbies=tennis,soccer,naps'
```

- I want to extract: `ralf,john,franky`
- The pattern here is: `mynames`
- The delimiter is: `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```
mynames=([^\s]+)
```

And then, look for the first group: `$1`

---

**Here is a live example in JavaScript (works also in other languages):**

```js
var regex = /mynames=([^\s]+)/;
var text = "toto=1,2,3 mynames=ralf,john,franky myhobbies=tennis,soccer,naps"

console.log(regex.exec(text)[1]);
```

---

If you are looking for a regex which does only match everything after `mynames=`, so that you don't need to look for the first group, you can also use a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=mynames=)[^\s]+
```

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/mem6mA/1

Comment: I am going to test and feedback. Thanks :)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know. Apparently some persons downvoted the question for some unknown reason.